# TFS: how to create an issue automatically on email

Tags: email, tfs

Is there any possibility to create a new issue in TFS when email is arrived on the certain address (email subject will be used as issue title, email body as content, email author as source for "CreatedBy")?

I guess, it is possible to write an application that will monitor incoming emails somehow,.. but is there any configuration options in the TFS (or in any other applications) that allow to do that without development?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Team Companion](http://www.ekobit.com/ProductsDetailView.aspx?id=1) to do this. This is not free, but probably your best shot.